# How to send data to multiple servers in spring boot micro service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have requirement something like this:
once the request is received by my service, i need to send it 2-3 third party servers at a time and get the response from all server and return the response.

How can I achieve that?. 
My thought : I can create separate threads for different servers and send the request to all servers parallely, but here the issue is, how I will come to know the threads are finished and consolidate the response from all servers and return to caller.

Is there any other way to do in spring boot(micro service)?.

Comment: third party servers are synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: You should probably go with some kind of pub sub system (maybe even Spring Integration supports that; not sure tho) and in asynchronous manner. Forget about "blocking while waiting for response". You fire request from your sender service -> third party servers receive message and respond -> your sender service receives a message and "publishes" it (like via server sent events or web socket).

Comment: @NarendraJaggi asynchronous..

Comment: @BranislavLazic could you please send some link with example even though it's exactly not matching to my requirement only for my understanding.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage asyn feature supported by Spring Framework. Let's see the folllowing example which issue multiple calls in Async style from Spring's official guides:[Async Method](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Another possible solution for internal communications between Microserives is to use the message queue.

Comment: If I am not wrong, Async method is to make our service asynchronous. But it's not the case. I want to send request to different servers asynchronously. Message queue sounds good. I will give a try. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what type of services are you consuming. If they are HTTP, you may want to use some Enterprise Integrations abstractions (most popular are Spring Integration and Apache Camel).

If you don't want to introduce message bus solution into your microservice, you may want to take a look at [`AsyncRestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html)

Comment: I am not consuming any 3rd party service. I want to send request to multiple third party server.

Comment: It may or may not describe same, depending on what type of technology are you going to use to send that request. Is that HTTP?

Comment: ,,yes it's http.